# Concat multiple shapefiles via geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to combine multiple shapefiles by implementing the follwing:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

for i in range(10,56):
    interesting_files = "/Users/m3105/Downloads/area/tl_2015_{}_arealm.shp".format(i)
    gdf_list = []
    for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
        gdf_list.append(gpd.read_file((filename)))
        full_gdf = pd.concat(gdf_list)
```

in which the directory `/Users/m3105/Downloads/area` has several shapefiles with such as `tl_2015_01_arealm.shp`, `tl_2015_02_arealm.shp` all the way up to `tl_2015_56_arealm.shp`. I'd like to combine all of these shapefiles and avoid repeating their headers. However, whenever I try concating the files using the code above, I get the following error:

`ValueError: Null layer: u''`

Normally, I'd know how to concat csv files together but I'm note sure how to concat shapefiles. I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: There seem to be several errors in your code to be able to run: `interesting_files` is a single string, so looping through it with `for filename in sorted(interesting_files):` will loop through the single characters of that filename. Further, the `pd.concat(gdf_list)` should be outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't test this since I don't have your data, but you want something like this (assuming python 3):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas
import geopandas

folder = Path("/Users/m3105/Downloads/area")
shapefiles = folder.glob("tl_2015_*_arealm.shp")
gdf = pandas.concat([
    geopandas.read_file(shp)
    for shp in shapefiles
]).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
gdf.to_file(folder / 'compiled.shp')
```

Answer (score 18):

If using pandas.concat like the answer of @Paul H, some geographical imformation such as coordinate reference system(crs) does not get preserved by default. But it worked when using the way like below:

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

file = os.listdir("Your folder")
path = [os.path.join("Your folder", i) for i in file if ".shp" in i]

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gpd.read_file(i) for i in path], 
                        ignore_index=True), crs=gpd.read_file(path[0]).crs)
```

In this way, the geodataframe will have CRS as your need

Comment: I have large datasets and this worked very fast!

Comment: That is so efficent!

Answer (score 1):

I've not enough rep to comment on last submission but after testing input files with differing CRS's,

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gpd.read_file(i) for i in path], 
                        ignore_index=True), crs=gpd.read_file(path[0]).crs)
```

should be

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gpd.read_file(i).to_crs(gpd.read_file(path[0]).crs) for i in path], 
                        ignore_index=True), crs=gpd.read_file(path[0]).crs)
```