# extract and merge several shapefiles from zipfile without saving to disc

Tags: python-3.x, zip, shapefile, geopandas, geo

First time I work with zipfiles in Python :-/

The task at hand is the following (main requirement is **not writing anything to disc**)

given this url: http://shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/ALL_HFIC.zip

- get the zipfile
- extract shapefiles from zip arcvhie which contain `Africa` in the file name.
- merge all files into one shapefile (read all files into geopandas).
- convert to geoJson.

This is the structure of the code I have so far - but I keep getting an attribute error

`AttributeError: 'ZipFile' object has no attribute 'seek'`

```
import io
import zipfile
import pandas as pd     
import geopandas as gpd 

# util funcs
is_africa = lambda string: "Africa" in string                                
is_shape = lambda string: string.endswith('shp')

# get_zip() defined in module
filebytes = io.BytesIO(get_zip(url=URL).content)  

# get the zipfile object
myzipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filebytes)
                                                               
# instantiate empty list where to store the shapefiles of interest.      
shapefiles = []

# below code adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917284/                                                                                               
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:                               
    for file_name in zf.namelist():                                      
        if is_africa(file_name) and is_shape(file_name):                 
            data = zf.read(file_name)                                    
            shapefiles.append(data)                                      


# below code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874113/                                                                         
gdf_africa = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gpd.read_file(i) for i in shapefiles], 
                                        ignore_index=True), 
                              crs=gpd.read_file(shapefiles[0]).crs)   

gdf_africa.to_file("output.json", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code requests the ZipFile from the URL, reads the ZipFile into a stream and extract the names of the ShapeFiles for Africa.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests

# util funcs
is_africa = lambda string: "Africa" in string
is_shape = lambda string: string.endswith('shp')

# instantiate empty list where to store the shapefiles of interest.
africa_data = []

response = requests.get('http://shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/ALL_HFIC.zip')
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as zf:
    for file_name in zf.namelist():
       if is_africa(file_name) and is_shape(file_name):
         print(file_name)
         # Output
         ALL_HFIC/ALL_HFIC/East Africa/EA_200907_CS.shp
         ALL_HFIC/ALL_HFIC/East Africa/EA_200910_CS.shp
         ALL_HFIC/ALL_HFIC/East Africa/EA_201001_CS.shp
         ALL_HFIC/ALL_HFIC/East Africa/EA_201004_CS.shp
```

I have ***never*** worked with ShapeFiles or geopandas.  I have spent the last 4 hours trying to understand how to use these.  I was able to output a JSON file, but I'm unsure if the data within this JSON file meets your needs.

```
# util funcs
is_africa = lambda string: "Africa" in string
is_shape = lambda string: string.endswith('shp')

# instantiate empty list where to store the shapefiles of interest.
africa_data = []

response = requests.get('http://shapefiles.fews.net.s3.amazonaws.com/ALL_HFIC.zip')
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as zf:
    for file_name in zf.namelist():
       if is_africa(file_name) and is_shape(file_name):
         reader = shapefile.Reader(file_name)
         fields = reader.fields[1:]
         field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
         for sr in reader.shapeRecords():
            atr = dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))
            geom = sr.shape.__geo_interface__
            africa_data.append(dict(type="Feature", geometry=geom, properties=atr))

    geojson = open("african_geo_data.json", "w")
    geojson.write(dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": africa_data}, indent=2) + "\n")
    geojson.close()
```

**Sample Out from the JSON file:**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
       "coordinates": [
         [
           [
            [
              40.213226318000125,
              -10.277393340999765
            ],
            [
              40.21355056800013,
              -10.279667853999932
            ],
            [
              40.21699915800019,
              -10.27847569599988
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
          "CS": 4.0,
          "HA0": 0.0
          }
        }
       ]
      }
```